# Main css in Admin

Tags: prestashop

I develop a module compatible Prestashop 1.3, 1.4, 1.5, 1.6

I try in the admin config panel of my module to make a preview design of the element in the shop. Can I have access of main css of shop in my admin config panel?

Thank you by advance

Comment: Please to read official documentation, it contains many paragraphs on how to manage css, inside module or outside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If the module needs to work with PrestaShop 1.4, the CSS files should be placed in a /css folder at the root of the module's folder.

http://doc.prestashop.com/display/PS16/Creating+a+first+module